# Hot File Clustering with multiple partitions

Tags: macos, partitioning, performance, defragment, hfs+

I'm planning a performance-oriented clean install of OS X 10.6 and I was wondering if the *hot file clustering* feature will exists only on the *boot partition* or if there will be one for each partition (even if it won't be on the most external part of the hard disk).

I wasn't able to find any specific documentation about this so, if you know something, your help would be greatly appreciated.